# How to find all .kl files in current directory with Flygrep (spacevim)

Tags: spacevim

I tried with `Flygrep *.kl` but it didn't work, I searched how to use `--include \*.kl` as in a grep search but I didn't find anything

Comment: while grepping is more for finding specific content, you could possibly try to use a very generic pattern that matches in every file, like `^` or `.`. That should give you a list of available files.

Answer (score 1):

A "standard vim" answer:

```
:args `find . -iname '*.kl'`
```

Substitute the `find` command for any command that can generate the list of files.

Then you can use `:next` and `:prev` for navigating (bound conveniently to `]a` and `[a` in tpope/unimpaired).

Further refinement:

```
:vimgrep /pattern/ ##
```

This searches the arglist (`##`) for the given `pattern`; you can use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to navigate (bound to `]q` and `[q` in tpope/unimpaired).

Answer (score 0):

Flygrep is a plugin for searching text. it do not for searching file path. if you want to searching file path, I recommended to use denite.nvim